# String as key for array in object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, var

I have an object like this:
`var object = {"American":[{"question":"What is the capital?", "answer":"..."}, ... ]};`
I have also a variable: 
`var language = "American";`

So, my question is: How can i use the variable called language as a key for the array with all the questions? I have already tried this: 
`object.language[0].question` and `object.[language][0].question`.

Comment: `object[language][0].question`

Comment: Well you do not use bracket notation correctly.... error in console should point that out with the extra `.`

Comment: object[language][0].question worked perfectly